# Install APM in kibana

Tags: installation, plugins, openshift, kibana, apm

I am currently using openshift platform, kibana is running as pod, the operator installed to collect logs:-
1)OpenShift Elasticsearch Operator.
2)Red Hat OpenShift Logging.
I would like to install the apm in kibana, can anyone help with?

I am not sure where and how to install apm